# State not persisting between functions with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am practicing React useState hooks to make a quiz with a ten second timer per question.

Currently I am able to get the quiz questions from an API, set them to state, and render them. If a user clicks an answer, the question is removed from the array in state, the seconds in state is reset to 10 and the next question renders.

I am trying to get the timer to clear when there is nothing left in the array of questions in state. When I console.log(questions) in the startTimer function, it is an empty array, despite the same console.log showing the data in the userAnswer function? What am I missing here?

I've removed the referenced shuffle function to save space

```
function App() {

  // State for trivia questions, time left, right/wrong count
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(10);
  const [correct, setCorrect] = useState(0);
  const [incorrect, setIncorrect] = useState(0);

  // Get data, set questions to state, start timer
  const getQuestions = async () => {
    let trivia = await axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
    trivia = trivia.data.results
    trivia.forEach(result => {
      result.answers = shuffle([...result.incorrect_answers, result.correct_answer])
    })
    setQuestions(trivia)
    startTimer()
  }

  const startTimer = () => {

    // Empty array here, but data at beginning of userAnswer
    console.log(questions)

    const interval = setInterval(() => {

      // If less than 1 second, increment incorrect, splice current question from state, clear interval and start timer back at 10
      setSeconds(time => {
        if (time < 1) {
          setIncorrect(wrong => wrong + 1)
          setQuestions(q => {
            q.splice(0,1)
            return q;
          })
          clearInterval(interval);
          startTimer()
          return 10;
        }
        // I want this to hold the question data, but it is not
        if (questions.length === 0) {
          console.log("test")
        }
        // Else decrement seconds 
        return time - 1;
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  // If answer is right, increment correct, else increment incorrect
  // Splice current question from const questions
  const userAnswer = (index) => {

    // Shows array of questions here
    console.log(questions)

    if (questions[0].answers[index] === questions[0].correct_answer) {
      setCorrect(correct => correct + 1)
    } else {
      setIncorrect(incorrect => incorrect + 1)
    }
    setQuestions(q => {
      q.splice(0,1);
      return q;
    })
    
    // Shows same array here despite splice in setQuestions above
    console.log(questions)
    setSeconds(10);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => getQuestions()}></button>
      {questions.length > 0 &&
        <div>
          <Question question={questions[0].question} />
          {questions[0].answers.map((answer, index) => (
            <Answer
              key={index}
              answer={answer}
              onClick={() => userAnswer(index)} />
          ))}
        </div>
      }
      <p>{seconds}</p>
      <p>Correct: {correct}</p>
      <p>Incorrect: {incorrect}</p>
    </div>

  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Each render of your `App` will create new bindings of its inner functions and variables (like `questions` and `startTimer`).

When the button is clicked and `getQuestions` runs, `getQuestions` then calls the `startTimer` function. At that point in time, the `startTimer` function closes over the `questions` variable that was defined at the time the button was clicked - *but it's empty* at that point. Inside the interval, although the function has re-rendered, the interval callback is still referencing the `questions` in the old closure.

Rather than depending on old closures, I'd initiate a  `setTimeout` on render (inside a `useLayoutEffect` so the timeout can be cleared if needed) if the `questions` array is populated.

Another issue is that `splice` should not be used with React, since that *mutates* the existing array - use non-mutating methods instead, like `slice`.

Try something like the following:

```
// Get data, set questions to state, start timer
const getQuestions = async () => {
  let trivia = await axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
  trivia = trivia.data.results
  trivia.forEach(result => {
    result.answers = shuffle([...result.incorrect_answers, result.correct_answer])
  })
  setQuestions(trivia);
  setSeconds(10);
}
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (!questions.length) return;
  // Run "timer" if the quiz is active:
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    setSeconds(time => time - 1);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
// If quiz is active and time has run out, mark this question as wrong
// and go to next question:
if (questions.length && time < 1) {
  setIncorrect(wrong => wrong + 1)
  setQuestions(q => q.slice(1));
  setSeconds(10);
}
if ((correct || incorrect) && !questions.length) {
  // Quiz done
  console.log("test")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I went with the other solution due to being more familiar with useEffect, but I will definitely be looking into useLayoutEffect soon.

Comment: You could use `useEffect` above instead of `useLayoutEffect`, the only reason I used `useLayoutEffect` is that it'll run a bit faster when the component is rendered; `useEffect` only runs after a delay. So, `useLayoutEffect` will result in a more accurate timer.

Comment: Apart from the timing issue, in this case, they behave identically.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this solution as well.  Thanks again.

Comment: This solution is definitely much cleaner and makes more sense than what I initially had.  
regarding this part:
`if ((correct || incorrect) && !questions.length)`
Should i then set `correct` and `incorrect` as null initially?   If I'm understanding this part right, it is testing if correct or incorrect are defined and there are no questions left.

Comment: It's testing whether at least one of `correct` or `incorrect` is non-zero, which will occur only if the quiz has been started. You could use `null` as an initial value too, if you wanted, but starting at 0 makes things a bit easier to work with, since then you can just add one to it when it comes to scoring.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of [closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).

When `getQuestions` executes this part:

```
    setQuestions(trivia)
    startTimer()
```

Both functions run in the same render cycle. In this cycle `questions` is still `[]` (or whatever previous value it held). So when you call `console.log(questions)` inside `startTimer`, you get an empty array.

You can fix that by invoking `startTimer` in the next render cycle with `useEffect`

```js
  const [ start, setStart ] = useState(false)
 
  const getQuestions = async () => {
    let trivia = await axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=9&difficulty=easy&type=multiple")
    trivia = trivia.data.results
    trivia.forEach(result => {
      result.answers = shuffle([...result.incorrect_answers, result.correct_answer])
    })
    setQuestions(trivia)
    setStart(true)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
   if (start) {
    startTimer();
    setStart(false)
   }
  },[start])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and helpful article. I had already been reading up on useEffect so I will go with this solution.

Comment: Cool, but @CertainPerformance raised an important point about `setInterval`'s callback which I overlooked. Inside the callback, the `questions` array will always have whatever values `trivia` initially had. This is again because of how closures work. If you just use `setQuestions` is fine, though.